# Is there a way to Get email and attachments from outlook add in using Client side JS?

Tags: office-addins

We are working on an outlook add-in which needs to send current email message as a .eml or .msg file and needs to be uploaded to SharePoint. Is there any Client Side JS for getting the email? Was looking to avoid any server side code if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide your current research.